# Print user role when submitting comments in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-theming

In my Drupal site, user profile has username, role and group Taxonomy term. There is a Article content type setup to take comments from users. Every time when a user comments, I would like to show as:

```
Submitted by: username, role, group
```

I tried to read the role and category fields through template_preprocess function as below:

```
function bartik_preprocess_comment(array &$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['elements']['#view_mode'])) {
    $variables['view_mode'] = $variables['elements']['#view_mode'];
  }
  else {
    $variables['view_mode'] = 'default';
  }
  dd($variables);
}
```

But the dump does not show "group" field. Unsure what's missing.Rightnow, only the username is showing up. My comments.html.twig looks as below:

```
  <div class="author-comments">
      <p class="comment-submitted">{{ submitted }}</p>
      <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('content') }}>
        {% if title %}
          {{ title_prefix }}
          <h3{{ title_attributes }}>{{ title }}</h3>
          {{ title_suffix }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </div>
```

any help on how to pull out the role and category field and plug into the twig template? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'm able to figure this out. Below is my answer:

In mytheme.theme file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for comment.html.twig.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_comment(array &$variables) {
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
  $user_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
                ->getStorage('user')
                ->load($user->id());

  $roles = $user->getRoles();
  $variables['user_roles'] = $roles ;
}
```

This variable can be printed on comment.html.twig as: `{{ user_roles }}` as however needed.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `$user = \Drupal::currentUser();`?? Wouldn't you want to get the user who authored the comment? You can see how the core comment module loads the comment author in the core comment [template_preprocess_comment function](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.5.x/core/modules/comment/comment.module#L565)

Comment: So the commentable capability is enabled for users who have login credentials. Basically for authorized users. That's why I had it as currentuser

Comment: Using `$user = \Drupal::currentUser();` If you are on a page with comments made by another user, then clear the render cache, this code would get your user, not the user who made the comment.

Comment: @2pha: What should be used instead of $user = \Drupal::currentUser(); ?

Comment: Check the $variables array, there should be something in there with the comment user object or id